# Checking table's checkbox triggers my dblclick (custom) event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a checkbox inside my table row. I also got a double click (custom) event on every 'tr' of this table to open a Boostrap 4 Modal. It works fine and it only fires when I double click on it, but if I check the checkbox in it, it triggers the event and opens the Modal. I never made any checkbox event.

HTML:

```
<tr>
   <td>
     <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
       <input id="checkboxL1" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input">
       <label class="custom-control-label" for="checkboxL1"></label>
     </div>
   </td>
       <td>Info1</td>
       <td>Info2</td>
       <td>Info3</td>
       <td>Valid</td>
 </tr>
```

Javascript:

```
var isDbl = false;
var timer = null;

$('#dataTable tbody')
    .on(
            'click',
            'tr',
            function() {

                clearTimeout(timer)
                timer = setTimeout(function() {
                    isDbl = false
                }, 250)
                if (isDbl) {

                var table = $('#dataTable').DataTable();

                if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {

                    $(this).attr("data-toggle", "modal");
                    $(this).attr("data-target", "#manageModal");
                    $(this).removeClass('selected');
                } else {
                    table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
                    $(this).attr("data-toggle", "modal");
                    $(this).attr("data-target", "#manageModal");
                    $(this).addClass('selected');
                }

                isDbl = false;
                } else {

                    $(this).removeAttr("data-toggle", "modal");
                    $(this).removeAttr("data-target", "#manageModal");
                    isDbl = true
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you I.R.R. since you gave me this idea. Stopping the event propagation of from the checkbox and label solved the issue. I just added the following code to my Datatable click event:

```
                $('.custom-control-label').click(function() {
                    event.stopPropagation();
                });

                $('.custom-control-input').click(function() {
                    event.stopPropagation();
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Totally a guess here, but I'm thinking your checkbox input triggers twice because clicking on it actually triggers the label which then triggers the checkbox. Result is two clicks.

Test with this to check if that is the case:

```
$('.custom-checkbox label').live('click', function (event) {
        alert('clicked');
});
```

If it is the case, adding this in your `$('#dataTable tbody')` click handler function should resolve that issue:

```
event.stopPropagation()
```